# Double Output In Program

Tags: java, swing, logic, output

When I run my code, I get the output twice instead of just once. What causes this? Also how can I output the amount of times it took the computer to guess the word? This is the current output: but when I enter a word it does the output twice?

```
Enter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!
nice 
Your word is: nice
Enter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!
```

The code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Hangman extends JApplet
{
    public void paint (Graphics Page)
    {
                //gallows
                Page.drawLine(0,300,20,300);
                Page.drawLine(10,40,10,300);
                Page.drawLine(10,40,80,40);
                Page.drawLine(80,40,80,55);

                //torso
                Page.drawOval(50,55,50,55);
                Page.drawOval(50,100,50,100);
                //left arm and hand
                Page.drawLine(50,150,40,110);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 45,100);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 25,100);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 25,115);


                //right arm and hand
                Page.drawLine(100,150,120,110);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 115,95);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 125,95);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 135,115);

                //left  leg and foot
                Page.drawLine(80,200,100,250);
                Page.drawLine(100,250, 115,260);


                //right leg and foot
                Page.drawLine(75,200,60,250);
                Page.drawLine(60,250,45,260);




     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!");



     String word = in.nextLine();




     char[] letter = word.toCharArray();


     for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
             letter[i] = 'a';
     }


     for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
         for (int j = 48; j < 122; j++) {

                     if (letter[i] == word.charAt(i)) { 
                             break; 
                     } else {
                             letter[i] = (char)((int) j + 1);
                     }
             }
     }
     System.out.println("Your word is: ");

     for (char letters : letter) {
             System.out.print(letters);
     }

}

}
```

Comment: Has to do with how `JApplets` have their `paint` method invoked. Don't do input there.

Comment: Somehow your `paint` method is invoking twice. Simple solution make another class/method for taking input.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use console input with a GUI based applications. User input should be gained by using one or more of the available UI controls.

Painting in Swing can occur for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control, this means that when ever Swing wants to update your UI, it will call paint, meaning you are constantly being asked to provide a new word

Also, you are blocking the paint process, this means until you paint method exits, it's unlikely that anything will be painted

Start by taking a look at [How to create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and, when you understand that, [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you put everything inside the paint function, it will be called again if the applet repaints. So you will notice if you don't resize the applet or do anything else that would cause it to repaint, then it will not have that double output. You can fix this by creating the applet from a main that contains the hangman text logic.

As for how to tell how many steps it took, you should have an extra counter initialized to 0 outside of the nested for loops and inside the inner nested for loop you should increment it. Since you break when the correct word is found, that counter will have the number of attempts.

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing console based input with GUI apps, especially with applets, as the "general" user is unlikely to have the applet console open, meaning they'll never be able to put input into the program